# Bad formatting using random.sample

Tags: python

I need to take a number `n` of random lines from a text file, and then write them into a new text file.
The code works but the lines are taken and written with a different format than that in the original file, and I want to keep the same.
This is the code:

```
import random

with open('textfile.dat') as f:
    lines = random.sample(f.readlines(),100) #n=100 for example

out=open('newfile.dat', 'w+') 
print >>out, lines
```

A small part of textfile.dat:

```
 626.0649 310.7645 122.8257
 626.1954 310.5412 123.0418
 627.0475 310.7212 123.2242
 626.6918 311.0145 123.6525
 ...
```

And a small part of newfile.dat:

```
['632.3587 304.9801 101.2915\n', '644.4067 307.2889 114.6692\n', '626.0014 312.0789 98.2628\n', '653.1418 307.1721 100.6861\n', ...
```

I'm using python 2.7 on macOS. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um... the counterpart of `readlines` is... drum roll... `writelines`.

```
out.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're writing out `lines`, which is a list, so it is printed using list representation - with brackets around and commas between items. What you want requires printing items in a loop, one by one:

```
for l in lines:
    print >>out, l
```

or better (because compatible with Python3):

```
for l in lines:
    out.write(l)
```

Oh, and don't forget to `out.close()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to write each line at a time.

```
for line in lines:
    print >> out, l
```

Answer (score 0):

You're writing the raw list rather than writing each item of the list individually.  This will also be forward compatible with Python 3:

```
with open('textfile.dat') as in_f, open('newfile.dat', 'w+') as out_f:
    out_f.writelines(random.sample(in_f.readlines(), 100))
```

Comment: @Stefan:  thanks - I forgot that `random.sample` chooses unique elements.  Edited to match OP's code.